# In compiling shogun machine learning toolbox for matlab interface, what are the necessary packages I need to install for cygwin?

Tags: matlab, cygwin, shogun

I don't want to install all as it consumes much space..

the following is what i'm sure is needed:

gcc, make python..

what else?

Answer (score 1):

On the site, in their documentation on installing...

http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/doc/en/current/installation.html

> **Requirements**
>
> SHOGUN requires the standard linux utils like bash, grep, test, sed,
> cut, ldd, uname gcc g++ and cat python (debian package: python2.4 or
> python2.5) for the ./configure to work.
>
> Optionally you will need atlas and lapack (debian packages
> lapack3-dev, atlas3-headers atlas3-base-dev or atlas3-altivec-dev
> atlas3-sse2-dev) installed. Note that atlas/lapack is only supported
> under linux (high performance computing should be done under linux
> only anyway). In case atlas/lapack is unavailable, don't worry most of
> shogun will work without, though slightly slower versions are used.
>
> To
> enable Multiple Kernel Learning with CPLEX(tm) just make sure cplex
> can be found in the PATH. If it is not found shogun will resort to
> GLPK (if version at least 4.29 is found) for 1-norm MKL, p-norm MKL
> with p>1 will work nonetheless.
>
> To compile the C# interface you need to have the C# developer files
> (debian package mono-utils) installed.
>
> To compile the Lua interface
> you need to have the Lua developer files (debian package lua)
> installed.
>
> To compile the Java interface you need to have the Java
> developer files (debian package openjdk-6-jdk) installed.
>
> To compile
> the R interface you need to have the R developer files (debian package
> r-base-dev) installed.
>
> To compile the Ruby interface you need to have
> the Ruby developer files (debian package ruby) installed.
>
> To compile
> the octave interface you need to have the octave developer files
> (debian package octave3.0-headers) installed.
>
> To compile the python
> interface you need to have numpy version 1.x installed (debian package
> python-numpy) installed.